# CORS. Why can chrome access my API?

Tags: cors

I've been reading about CORS and I built a simple Rails API. I am trying to build an Angular client to consume it and I know how to allow this by adding allow-access-headers to the server. But currently, why can chrome consume this api? If I go to the API endpoint using chrome by typing in the address in my URL bar, I can see the JSON data. Why is this even though I haven't done anything to the server to allow CORS.

Comment: What do you mean by “if I go to the API endpoint”? Are you calling the URL directly in your browser, by typing it into the address bar? Then of course none of the restrictions CORS lifts are applicable in the first place.

Comment: I was going to type an answer, but the duplicate really had a complete explanation.

Comment: How can I look up duplicates in the future more easily?

Comment: @bmargulies I still don't get why my browser can make a request using the url address bar but not an AJAX request.

Comment: @Jwan622: Again, the same-origin policy applies to Ajax requests specifically, but not the browser in general. If you type the URL into the address bar, then *you* are making the request, not a page.

Comment: @FelixKling"then you are making the request, not a page"? So when my browser makes a request, it's cool? But when it requests a page it is not? What is a page here?

Answer (score 3):

> Why is this even though I haven't done anything to the server to allow CORS.

Only **Ajax** requests are subject to the same-origin policy and affected by CORS. "Normal" HTTP requests, such as performed by the browser when you type the URL into the address bar, are not.

Comment: Ah I totally missed this.

Comment: But from the MDN site: "Cross-site HTTP requests are HTTP requests for resources from a different domain than the domain of the resource making the request.  For instance, a resource loaded from Domain A (http://domaina.example) such as an HTML web page, makes a request for a resource on Domain B (http://domainb.foo), such as an image, using the img element (http://domainb.foo/image.jpg).  This occurs very commonly on the web today — pages load a number of resources in a cross-site manner, including CSS stylesheets, images and scripts, and other resources."

Comment: I guess it's not only Ajax requests then...